# Curved textview is not displayed

Tags: java, android, wear-os

I am working on an android wear app. I would like to implement the CurvedTextView in my NestedScrollView. Outside of the NestedScrollView the CurvedTextView is displayed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.wear.widget.BoxInsetLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainConstraintLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?attr/colorBackground"
    tools:context=".Activitys.MainActivity2"
    tools:deviceIds="wear">

    <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/mainNestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fadingEdgeLength="30dp"
        android:requiresFadingEdge="vertical"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.wear.widget.CurvedTextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewClock"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textColor="@color/colorText"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                tools:text="12:00" />


            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/mainRecyclerView"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/mainButtonMenu"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

I tried to put the CurvedTextView into an ArcLayout but it doesn't help